# KeePassXC упорно не хочет открывать БД

Tags: linux, password, kubuntu, ubuntu-software

Раньше всё как-то не доходили руки до менеджеров паролей. Тут решил создать БД в `KeePassXC`. Просто создаю криптоконтейнер со всеми дефолтными настройками, лочу БД, пытаюсь релогиниться - и на тебе:

> *Error while reading the database: Invalid credentials were provided,
> please try again. If this reoccurs, then your database file may be
> corrupt. (HMAC mismatch)*

Несколько раз создавал новые БД с разными настройками - одна фигня. **Что может быть не так?** Поисковик ничего дельного не выдаёт. Фигню на форумах какую-то обсуждают: то диск битый, то RAM не такая, чушь всякая в общем. Новую базу каждый раз создаю. Сделал update-upgrade, заребутился. Нет толка.

**PS#1:**  Что-то расхотелось мне пользоваться этим хламом. Вот так все пароли потеряешь... Никакой надёжности.

**PS#2:** 
Верcия KeePassXC: `2.4.3+dfsg.1-1build1` 
Версия ядра: `5.15.0-71-generic` 
Версия Kubuntu: `Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS`

**PS#3:** 
Версию обновил - проблема осталась:

```bash
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phoerious/keepassxc
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ apt show keepassxc
Package: keepassxc
Version: 2.7.4-1ppa2~focal1
```

**PS#4:** 
Скачал [отсюда](https://keepassxc.org/download/#linux) исполняемый файл - работает.

Comment: У меня всё работает. Добавьте больше подробностей — какая версия KeePassXC, какая версия Kubuntu, откуда и как установили, воспроизводится ли проблема в чистой виртуальной машине?

Comment: Старовата версия, сейчас уже 2.7.4 есть

Comment: @andreymal, это да, но не вижу проблемы на смом деле. Это версия, которая ставится из `apt` Kubuntu 20.04. Не билдить же мне его, хотя можно попробовать

Comment: Поставил Kubuntu 20.04.6 и KeePassXC 2.4.3 в виртуалке, попробовал разные настройки — всё отлично работает

Comment: @andreymal, Очень интересно `¯ \ _ (ツ) _ / ¯`